# How does Go write code and execute system commands to start a new terminal as a result?

Tags: go

When I execute an ordinary command in Go code, for example `ls -ls`, it can be executed normally and return the result:

```golang
// Error handling is omitted, in fact there is error handling in my code

func main() {
    for {
        var stdout bytes.Buffer
        cmd := exec.Command("sh","-c","ls -ls")
        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Run()
        fmt.Println(stdout.String())
    }
}
```

The execution results are as follows：

```
[root@10-x-x-xx /root]# go run main.go
/usr/bin/sh -c ls -ls
stdout: total 8
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 358 Aug 14 23:09 main.go
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 167 Aug 14 16:07 temp.yaml
```

But when I execute a command to start a new terminal (not sure if my understanding is correct), the program returns normally with no errors, no output, and no jump to the new terminal.

For example: `nsenter -n --target PID`. This is a command to enter the network namespace. Normally, it will return to a "#" and enter successfully.

```
// Error handling is omitted, in fact there is error handling in my code

func main() {
    for {
        var stdout bytes.Buffer
        cmd := exec.Command("sh","-c","nsenter -n --target 123")
        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Run()
        fmt.Println(stdout.String())
    }
}
```

The program exits after the execution is complete, but does not actually enter the network namespace.

But when I use python, there is no such problem, it is executable.

```py
import os
os.system("nsenter -n --target 24347")
```

Or another question, how to write code in Go, so that I can execute this code to ssh to other hosts, I feel that this seems to be the same problem.

Comment: "sh", "-c" should not be necessary in these commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems there.

First, you're trying to spawn an interactive command (`nsenter` will by default start a shell in the target namespace), but you're also connecting *stdout* to a variable, which means even if it works you wouldn't be able to see any output until *after* the command exits, which is probably not what you want.

Secondly, you're not connecting *stdin* to anything useful, which means that most interactive commands will simply exit.

To start an interactive subcommand in Go, you would write something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "--norc")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Env = os.Environ()
    cmd.Env = append(cmd.Env, "PS1=example$ ")
    cmd.Run()
}
```

(This starts a `bash` shell with the prompt `example$` )

The key here is that we're connecting *stdin*, *stdout*, and *stderr*
to the corresponding descriptors of the parent process, which allows
us to interact with the subprocess.

If you weren't trying to start an interactive shell, what you have now
would work.  That is, you could write:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "nsenter", "-n", "--target", "2399896", "ip", "addr")
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println(stdout.String())
}
```

The above works just fine and displays the results of running `ip addr` inside the target network namespace.

Note that you might more typically using the `Output` method from the
`exec`module:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "nsenter", "-n", "--target", "2399896", "ip", "addr")
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(stdout))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there is another question I want to know: `cmd.Stdout = &stdout` and `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout`, is there any difference?

Comment: Yes, which I tried to explain in this answer. Setting `cmd.Stdout = &stdout`, which in your code is defined as `var stdout bytes.Buffer`, collects the stdout of the process into a variable. Setting `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout` connects stdout of the process to the stdout of your Go program, so you see the output on the console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will learn more about this information later.